# What does case _: mean in scala

Tags: scala

For example:

```
    castType match {                                                                                  
      case _: ByteType => datum.toByte  
      case _: ShortType => datum.toShort                                                              
      case _: IntegerType => datum.toInt
      case _ => throw new RuntimeException(s"Unsupported type: ${castType.typeName}") 
    }
```

What exactly does *: do? '*' is a placeholder and would usually mean "matching anything", but what does the ":" do? And How is the type "ByteType" treated?

Answer (score 11):

`case _ : ByteType =>` means that the matched object has to be of type `ByteType`

The whole `match` statement could also be written as a series of `if` statements:

```
if (castType.isInstanceOf[ByteType]) {
   datum.toByte
} else if (castType.isInstanceOf[....
...
```

But that would be quite ugly, wouldn't it?

Comment: wouldn't that be the case without the "_:" as well?

Comment: No. `case _ => ` does not check for the type, so it would match anything (similar to `default` in Java). `case _ : ByteType` matches only an instance of `ByteType`. It is the same like `case x : ByteType`, just without binding the casted matched object to a name `x`.

Comment: @EugeneMi `case ByteType:` matches against an `object` named `ByteType` (maybe the companion object of `class ByteType`). And `case _: ByteType` matches against an instance of `type` named `ByteType`.

Comment: `case ByteType =>` is something different. That checks for equality with an object `ByteType`. So `case _ : ByteType` is like `if (castType.isInstanceOf[ByteType])`. `case ByteType` is like `(castType == ByteType)`. Which variant you can use depends on what `ByteType` actually is. Is it a type, or an object?

Comment: ByteType is a type. The code is inside a function:  def castTo(datum: String, castType: DataType). I want to be able to call the function like this TypeCast.castTo("123", IntegerType) or TypeCast.castTo("true", BooleanType). Where IntegerType and BooleanType are companion objects that inherit from DataType

Comment: @Gregor Raýman, so when does the extractor (unapply method) gets called?

Comment: Simplified: the extractor gets called, when the `case` looks like this: `a match { case x(y) => ...`. This will call `x.unapply(a)` and the optional result will be bound to `y`. (It depends whether the `unapply` returns an `Option` or `boolean`.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the comments on the above answer are actually helpful unlike the answer itself.

`case _ : ByteType` is like `if (castType.isInstanceOf[ByteType])` while  `case ByteType` is like `(castType == ByteType)`

This way of writing case is specially helpful in DecimalTypes where precision could vary.

```
case _: DecimalType =>
```

For example, see [SchemaConverters](https://github.com/spotify/spark-bigquery/blob/ab8fd9cad7b574d4d56d68c7bbb65dd605666c0e/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/avro/SchemaConverters.scala#L369)